# Can I square both sides while calculating the Range of a function

Tags: elementary-functions

Let $f(x)=$ $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}$ is a given function. We have to find its range.
I have tried two approaches:-

1. $\sqrt{x-5}>0$
   ⇒ $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}>0$
   ⇒ $y>0$
   ⇒ Range = $(0,∞)$
2. $f(x)=y=$ $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}$
   ⇒ $y^2$=$\dfrac{1}{{x-5}}$
   ⇒ $x=5+$ $\dfrac{1}{{y^2}}$
   ⇒ Range = R – {$0$}
   The ranges found are not the same.

My view is that, this happened because in the 2nd approach, when I squared both sides, the function is changed. And what I had calculated is the range of $y^2=\dfrac{1}{{x-5}}$ instead of $y=$ $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}$.

Is this statement correct?

Comment: In your second method, you need to note both $x\gt 5$, and that $y>0$.  So $\operatorname{Range} = (0, \infty)$  because with $x\gt 5$, $x-5 \gt 0$, which requires $\frac 1{y^2} \gt 0$ which implies $y\gt 0$.

Comment: @amWhy: I am not interested in the range. My statement is that, in the 2nd approach, what I have calculated, is actually the range of $y^2$=$\dfrac{1}{{x-5}}$ instead of  $y=$ $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}$.  Is this statement correct?

Comment: Yes. correct... In your second approach, you did **not** calculate the range of $y=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}$.

Comment: Again, yes, the answer to your most recent edit is yes, your conclusion is correct.

Answer (score 1):

The range is $(0,\infty )$. Moreover, your argument is not correct. For example, $|\arctan(x)|\geq 0$, but it's range is $[0,\frac{\pi}{2}]$.

The argument is if $f(x)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}$, then $f(x)>0$ for all $x>5$ and $$\lim_{x\to \infty }f(x)=0 \quad \text{and}\quad \lim_{x\to 5}=+\infty .$$ Therefore, by Intermediate value theorem, $$\text{Im}(f)=(0,\infty ).$$

Comment: No problem.  +1 earlier :-)

Answer (score 1):

You simply forgot, in your second approach, that 
$$A=\sqrt{\mathstrut B}\iff A^2=B \quad\textbf{and}\quad {A \ge 0}  $$

Comment: No, it's only because the symbol $\sqrt B$ denotes conventionally the *nonnegative* square root of a (nonnegative) number. The right side of the equivalence implies $B\ge 0$.

Comment: Except in this case, $y = \frac 1{\sqrt{x -5}} \neq 0$.  Clearly, $x\gt 5$, and $y\gt 0$.

Comment: Of course, here, there's one more constraint.

Comment: Indeed, $x\gt 5, y \gt 0$.  So you oversimplified your general rule.  It depends on B.  $A= \sqrt B \iff A^62 = B$ **and** the definition of $B$, which determines what non-negative values $A$ can take on.

Comment: This general rule supposes only $A$ and $B$  are (well-defined) real numbers.

Comment: Well, in this case, $B$ is well defined for $x>5$, so me must have that A>0$.

Comment: $B$ defined for $x>5$  ensures $A$ is defined, but $B$ has two square roots. Once again the symbol in use means the nonnegative square root (or the positive square root when one is sure it is  not $0$), but this is purely a convention.

Comment: @Bernard: Is this statement correct that 'in the 2nd approach when I squared both sides, the function is changed and what I have calculated, is actually the range of $y^2$=$\dfrac{1}{{x-5}}$ instead of  $y=$ $\dfrac{1}{\sqrt{x-5}}$?'

Comment: Well, it's hard to say, because  $y^2$ cannot take any value  since $y^2 can't be negative (if $y$ is real, of course), so it eliminates the negative numbers. In my opinion, you forgot the sign constraint – which, all in all, is more or less what I answered.

Comment: $y^2$ term cannot be negative that is ok, but $y^2=\dfrac{1}{{x-5}}$ is a function which contains an even power of y, so it is symmetric about x-axis. Hence, it takes negative values too.

Comment: $y$ can take negative values, not $y^2$. You seem to be confusing $y$ and $y^2$.

Comment: No, I have asked that what I have calculated in the second approach is the range of $y^2=\dfrac{1}{{x-5}}$? And in response to that you have commented that "it's hard to say," and "it eliminates the negative numbers." thats why I mentioned that.

Comment: Speaking of symmetry w.r.t. the $x$-axis, you implicitly refer to $y$, not $y^2$.

Answer (score 0):

So you have to find all $y$ such that exist $x$ which satisfies $y= {1\over \sqrt{x-5}}$. Clearly, $y>0$ so $\operatorname{Range}(f)\subseteq (0,\infty)$.   Now we solve this equation on $x$ and we get $$x= 5+{1\over y^2}$$ and we see, no matter what positive $y$ is, we can calculate $x$, and thus $\operatorname{Range}(f)= (0,\infty)$.

Comment: I had previously  been your first upvote.  I know perfectly well that $y$ must be positive.  You're complaining to the wrong person.